# Share data format spec with multiple functions in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Given something like this:

```
/**
 * @brief FuncA
 *
 * Data format:
 * INT32 Date
 * INT32 Time
 * FLOAT Value
 *
 */
void funcA()
{}

/**
 * @brief FuncB
 *
 * Data format:
 * INT32 Date
 * INT32 Time
 * FLOAT Value
 *
 */
void funcB()
{}
```

How can I factor out the data format spec so it's not duplicated in multiple places? What I want is something like this:

```
/**
 * @magictag Data Format
 *
 * INT32 Date
 * INT32 Time
 * FLOAT Value
 */

/**
 * @brief FuncA
 *
 * Data format:
 * @ref DataFormat
 *
 */
void funcA()
{}

/**
 * @brief FuncB
 *
 * Data format:
 * @ref DataFormat
 *
 */
void funcB()
{}
```

I just want to have a generic blob of documentation that I can reference from any number of places. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at `\copydetails` and `\snippet...` so the information is coupled. Another possibility is with `\anchor`. Which version of doxygen?

Comment: Version 1.8.11.. I can't get \copydetails and \snippet to do what I need. \page kinda does what I want, but with \ref it creates a link to a separate HTML page. Ideally I would like the common doxy to be inlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of doxygen is 1.8.16, it is advised to upgrade to this version. With version 1.8.11 the `\snippetdoc` does not work (command didn't exist in this version).

**An example with `\copydetails`**:

```
/** \file */

/**
 * @brief FuncA
 *
 * Data format:
 * - INT32 Date
 * - INT32 Time
 * - FLOAT Value
 *
 */
void funcA();

/**
 * @brief FuncB
 *
 * @copydetails funcA
 */
void funcB();
```

**An example with `\snippetdoc`**:

```
/** \file */

/**
 * @brief FuncC
 *
 * @snippetdoc this snip_data
 *
 */
void funcC();

/**
 * @brief FuncD
 *
 * @snippetdoc this snip_data
 */
void funcD();


/*
 [snip_data]
  Data format:
  - INT32 Date
  - INT32 Time
  - FLOAT Value
 [snip_data]
*/
```

Comment: Upgrade is not possible at this time. I will select your answer, though, since \snippetdoc is probably what I would want if I could update. It also happens to be the only answer ;) Thanks.